# collapsible gridview cell ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on Gridview in ASP.NET(C#) and have cells that need to have as follwing example,

```
+ View
```

And, once user click on the "+View", I want to display the info on the same cell.

```
- Name:Tom Age: 16
```

And,, it will go back "+View" when user clicks on the cell
So, basically what i need is collapsible gridview, I am looking for a way to do this without Ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: Try jQuery [toggleSlide](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function or the equivalent in your JS framework of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of examples use AJAX for [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ExpandPanelGridView.aspx), but there are some examples without it. Like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CollapsiblePaneInGridView.aspx) one, and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/EditNestedGridView.aspx) one. They have a little javascript in them, but not AJAX.